# R - MLR - Classifier Calibration - Benchmark Results

Tags: mlr

I've run a benchmark experiment with nested cross validation (tuning + performance measurement) for a classification problem and would like to create calibration charts.

If I pass a benchmark result object to generateCalibrationData, what does plotCalibration do? Is it averaging? If so how?

Does it make sense to have an aggregate = FALSE option to understand variability across folds as per generateThreshVsPerfData for ROC curves?

In response to @Zach's request for a reproducible example, I (the OP) edit my original post as follows:

Edit: Reproducible Example

```
# Practice Data

library("mlr")
library("ROCR")
library(mlbench)

data(BreastCancer)
dim(BreastCancer)
levels(BreastCancer$Class)
head(BreastCancer)

BreastCancer <- BreastCancer[, -c(1, 6, 7)]
BreastCancer$Cl.thickness <- as.factor(unclass(BreastCancer$Cl.thickness))
BreastCancer$Cell.size <- as.factor(unclass(BreastCancer$Cell.size))
BreastCancer$Cell.shape <- as.factor(unclass(BreastCancer$Cell.shape))
BreastCancer$Marg.adhesion <- as.factor(unclass(BreastCancer$Marg.adhesion))
head(BreastCancer)

# Define Nested Cross-Validation Strategy

cv.inner <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 2, stratify = TRUE)
cv.outer <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 6, stratify = TRUE)

# Define Performance Measures

perf.measures <- list(auc, mmce)

# Create Task

bc.task <- makeClassifTask(id = "bc",
                           data = BreastCancer, 
                           target = "Class", 
                           positive = "malignant")

# Create Tuned KSVM Learner

ksvm <- makeLearner("classif.ksvm", 
                    predict.type = "prob")

ksvm.ps <- makeParamSet(makeDiscreteParam("C", values = 2^(-2:2)),
                        makeDiscreteParam("sigma", values = 2^(-2:2)))

ksvm.ctrl <- makeTuneControlGrid()

ksvm.lrn = makeTuneWrapper(ksvm, 
                           resampling = cv.inner,
                           measures = perf.measures,
                           par.set = ksvm.ps, 
                           control = ksvm.ctrl, 
                           show.info = FALSE)

# Create Tuned Random Forest Learner

rf <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest", 
                  predict.type = "prob", 
                  fix.factors.prediction = TRUE)

rf.ps <- makeParamSet(makeDiscreteParam("mtry", values = c(2, 3, 5)))

rf.ctrl <- makeTuneControlGrid()

rf.lrn = makeTuneWrapper(rf, 
                         resampling = cv.inner,
                         measures = perf.measures,
                         par.set = rf.ps, 
                         control = rf.ctrl, 
                         show.info = FALSE)

# Run Cross-Validation Experiments

bc.lrns = list(ksvm.lrn, rf.lrn)

bc.bmr <- benchmark(learners = bc.lrns, 
                    tasks = bc.task, 
                    resampling = cv.outer, 
                    measures = perf.measures, 
                    show.info = FALSE)

# Calibration Charts

bc.cal <- generateCalibrationData(bc.bmr)
plotCalibration(bc.cal)
```

Produces the following:

[Aggregared Calibration Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cq3r.png)

Attempting to un-aggregate leads to:

```
> bc.cal <- generateCalibrationData(bc.bmr, aggregate = FALSE)

Error in generateCalibrationData(bc.bmr, aggregate = FALSE) : 

  unused argument (aggregate = FALSE)

> 

> sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)

attached base packages:

[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:

[1] mlbench_2.1-1     ROCR_1.0-7        gplots_3.0.1      mlr_2.9           
[5] stringi_1.1.1     ParamHelpers_1.10 ggplot2_2.1.0     BBmisc_1.10           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

 [1] digest_0.6.9        htmltools_0.3.5     R6_2.2.0            splines_3.2.3          
 [5] scales_0.4.0        assertthat_0.1      grid_3.2.3          stringr_1.0.0          
 [9] bitops_1.0-6        checkmate_1.8.2     gdata_2.17.0        survival_2.38-3        
[13] munsell_0.4.3       tibble_1.2          randomForest_4.6-12 httpuv_1.3.3           
[17] parallelMap_1.3     mime_0.5            DBI_0.5-1           labeling_0.3           
[21] chron_2.3-47        shiny_1.0.0         KernSmooth_2.23-15  plyr_1.8.4             
[25] data.table_1.9.6    magrittr_1.5        reshape2_1.4.1      kernlab_0.9-25         
[29] ggvis_0.4.3         caTools_1.17.1      gtable_0.2.0        colorspace_1.2-6       
[33] tools_3.2.3         parallel_3.2.3      dplyr_0.5.0         xtable_1.8-2           
[37] gtools_3.5.0        backports_1.0.4     Rcpp_0.12.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no `plotCalibration` doesn't do any averaging, though it can plot a smooth.

if you call `generateCalibrationData` on a benchmark result object it will treat each iteration of your resampled predictions as exchangeable and compute the calibration across all resampled predictions for that bin.

yes it probably would make sense to have an option to generate an unaggregated calibration data object and be able to plot it. you are welcome to open an issue on GitHub to that effect, but this is going to be low on my priority list TBH.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If no averaging is taking place and assuming a k-fold cross validation, does that mean that all the (actual, predicted) pairs from each of the k-folds are placed in one bucket (i.e., treated as if they were derived from a single fold) and then the plot is created? AFAIK, generateCalibrationData does not support an 'aggregate = FALSE' option, see [link](https://rdrr.io/cran/mlr/man/generateCalibrationData.html)?

Comment: yea sorry i was looking at the wrong function. you should get an unaggregated result. post a reproducible example if this isn't the case.

Comment: please see the edit I have made to my original post which provides a reproducible example that I do not get unaggregated results.